# angular phonecat tutorial protractor testcase failure

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, protractor

I've just installed the angular phonecat tutorial [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) on an old laptop running Lubuntu 14.04. When I run `npm run protractor` it fails on the 5th testcase listed in the scenarios.js file. The testcase in question is:

```
it('should display nexus-s page', function() {
    expect(element(by.binding('phone.name')).getText()).toBe('Nexus S');
});
```

the response at the terminal I get is:

```
selenium standalone is up to date.
chromedriver is up to date.

> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor /home/david/angular-phonecat
> protractor test/protractor-conf.js

Using ChromeDriver directly...
....F..

Failures:

  1) PhoneCat App Phone detail view should display nexus-s page
   Message:
     Expected '' to be 'Nexus S'.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Failed expectation
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/home/david/angular-phonecat/test/e2e/scenarios.js:84:59)

Finished in 19.212 seconds
7 tests, 11 assertions, 1 failure


npm ERR! angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor: `protractor test/protractor-conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-phonecat@0.0.0 protractor script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the angular-phonecat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor test/protractor-conf.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-phonecat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-39-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "protractor"
npm ERR! cwd /home/david/angular-phonecat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/david/angular-phonecat/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I'm running this on a fairly old laptop so I wonder if its a performance issue.